# Postgresql postman sending null value

Tags: postgresql, express

I am trying to learn postgresql with express js and currently trying to send in a test "name" value to my backend database but everytime it is sent is being stored and returned as null. Here is my current server.js which express is ran out of:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const PORT = 5000;


//
//Middleware
//
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))



//
//Routes
//

//Add to cart
app.post("/addCart", async(req,res) =>{
    try {
        const { description } = req.body;
        const newName = await pool.query(
            "INSERT INTO products(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING *", 
            [description]
            );
        res.json(newName.rows[0]);

    } catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log("Express Server has started on port", {PORT});
});
```

and this is my postman body:

```
{
    "name": "testtest"
}
```

and this is the response being returned:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": null
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're pulling the wrong attribute out of the request body. Try changing description to name in your code:

```
try {
-    const { description } = req.body;
+    const { name } = req.body;
    const newName = await pool.query(
        "INSERT INTO products(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING *", 
-        [description]
+        [name]
        );
    res.json(newName.rows[0]);
```

Comment: Oh crap i dint realize { description } was what it pulled i just assumed it was a variable name we used, i appreciate it!